# MariaDB command line output misaligned and cutting off first character

Tags: database, mariadb

I am running a MariaDB database for my Databases class. I have had little to no trouble with it up until this point. I actually don't know how long I've been having this problem...

When I run SELECT queries, the far left bar is misaligned and is not displaying the first character of the output table.

Example:

```
Select * from airline;

+-------+------+
| id    | name |
+-------+------+
  |9393 | WN
  |9690 | HA
  |9790 | DL
  |9805 | AA
  |9930 | AS
  |9977 | UA
  |0304 | OO
  |0366 | EV
  |0409 | B6
  |0416 | NK
  |0436 | F9
  |1171 | VX
+-------+------+
```

And it should be

```
+-------+------+
| id    | name |
+-------+------+
| 19393 | WN
| 19690 | HA
| 19790 | DL
| 19805 | AA
| 19930 | AS
| 19977 | UA
| 20304 | OO
| 20366 | EV
| 20409 | B6
| 20416 | NK
| 20436 | F9
| 21171 | VX
+-------+------+
```

What am I doing wrong? Is anything wrong? The query is correct, I ran it through PHPMyAdmin's and HeidiSQL's query tool and had it return the proper display.

Is this a problem with MariaDB and command line?

Thank you

EDIT:

This is only a problem with some SELECT queries. About half of my tables return properly.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody or something inserts `name`s with carriage return.

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE airline (id INT, name CHAR(8));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO airline VALUES (12345,'AA');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM airline;
+-------+------+
| id    | name |
+-------+------+
| 12345 | AA   |
+-------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So far, so good. But

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO airline VALUES (12345,'BB\r');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM airline;
+-------+------+
| id    | name |
+-------+------+
| 12345 | AA   |
  |2345 | BB
+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The data is still there, though:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT id FROM airline;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 12345 |
| 12345 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You know, this make way too much sense... I gave up and did all my queries through a gui, but now I know to make sure to not insert \r's in my database...  Though I don't know how to fix it right now...Thank you so much!

Comment: Fixing it should be relatively easy. For existing values, just update `name` column to get rid of carriage returns -- under no circumstances should they be there anyway, right? Something like `UPDATE airline SET name = REPLACE(name,"\r",'')` (it's just an example, check it on a test table first!). For future, if you can't ensure that it does not happen again, you can add a trigger on the table before insert to strip the carriage return.